# How to connect local machine to AD DC running in AWS or Azure without VPN OR Point to Site

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, active-directory, local

I have a couple of local machines I want to authenticate the users from Active Directory ( Domain Controller)  running on the cloud Aws or Azure. how can I connect the local machine to the domain controller? which one is the best solutions

Comment: did you already look at Azure AD B2C ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/hybrid-azuread-join-manual-steps

Answer (score 1):

If your domain controller is running in a cloud provider and you want to have machines on your local network connect to it, then these machines need to have connectivity to the various AD services. You are not going to want to expose these services directly over the internet, so you are going to need some sort of private connection between your network and the cloud provider.

This could be a VPN or using one of the cloud providers direct connect services like ExpressRoute for Azure or Direct Connect for AWS.

The bigger question would be what you are trying to achieve here. Having your domain controllers in a completely different location to your clients, relying on connectivity to a cloud provider is not an ideal situation.

Comment: I am trying I have domain controller is running in Aws and couple of machines running in local. I want that local machine authenticates from Domain controller.

in case of VPN first, I need to connect VPN then only it will authenticate but I need. local machine auth directly with DC.

Comment: Not sure what your question is?